# Is there an instance of Monad but not of MonadFix?

Tags: haskell, monads, monadfix

The question is mostly in the title. It seems like `mfix` can be defined for any monadic computation, even though it might diverge:

```
mfix :: (a -> m a) -> m a
mfix f = fix (join . liftM f)
```

What is wrong with this construction? Also, why are the `Monad` and `MonadFix` typeclasses separate (i.e. what type has an instance of `Monad` but not of `MonadFix`)?

Comment: The continuation monad does not have the desired fixpoint operator.

Comment: See also [Why can't there be an instance of MonadFix for the continuation monad?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25827227/1333025).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [left shrinking (or tightening) law says](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-Fix.html#t:MonadFix) that

```
mfix (\x -> a >>= \y -> f x y)  =  a >>= \y -> mfix (\x -> f x y)
```

In particular this means that

```
mfix (\x -> a' >> f x)  =  a' >> mfix f
```

which means that the monadic action inside `mfix` must be evaluated exactly once. This is one of the main properties of `MonadFix` which your version fails to satisfy.

Consider this example that creates a cyclic mutable list (let's disregard the fact that you could do that without `mfix` thanks to mutability):

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Fix
import Data.IORef

data MList a = Nil | Cons a (IORef (MList a))

mrepeat :: a -> IO (MList a)
mrepeat x = mfix (liftM (Cons x) . newIORef)

main = do
    (Cons x _) <- mrepeat 1
    print x
```

With your variant of `mfix` the call to `mrepeat` never finishes, as you're calling the inner part with `newIORef` indefinitely.

Answer (score 6):

Your definition of `mfix` is not guaranteed to be equivalent to the standard one. In fact, at least in the list monad it is stricter:

```
> take 1 $ mfix (\x -> [1,x])
[1]
> let mfix2 :: Monad m => (a -> m a) -> m a; mfix2 f = fix (join . liftM f)
> take 1 $ mfix2 (\x -> [1,x])
Interrupted.
```