# What does fixIO do?

Tags: haskell

The [System.IO docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.5.0.0/docs/System-IO.html) contains a mysterious, undocumented function `fixIO`. [Its source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.5.0.0/docs/src/System-IO.html#fixIO) only adds to the mystery:

```
fixIO :: (a -> IO a) -> IO a
fixIO k = do
    m <- newEmptyMVar
    ans <- unsafeInterleaveIO (takeMVar m)
    result <- k ans
    putMVar m result
    return result
```

This appears to do the moral equivalent of dereferencing NULL (reading from an empty MVar). Indeed, trying it:

```
import System.IO
main = fixIO $ \x -> putStrLn x >> return x
```

results in an error "thread blocked indefinitely in an MVar operation"

Searching turns up nothing save a [15 year old message](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell/2001-February/006720.html) from Simon Peyton-Jones himself, in which he provides the above source, and hopes that it would make the meaning clear (and yet here I am).

Can someone please shed some light on this? What does fixIO do and when should I use it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`fixIO` is the `IO` equivalent of [`fix`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Function.html#v:fix).

You've probably seen this definition of the fibonacci sequence:

```
fibs = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

which reuses the `fibs` variable within the definition of `fibs` to do corecursion. It works because we exploit laziness to define each element of `fibs` before it needs to be used.

We can use `fix` to do the same without having to define a variable, [tying the knot](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tying_the_Knot) for us:

```
fix $ \fibs -> 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

Which is handy if you don't especially need to keep the entire fibonacci sequence, you just want to know its tenth element:

```
λ (fix $ \fibs -> 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)) !! 9
55
```

`fixIO` is similar, except it lets you recurse on the output of an IO action. That's why you got your "thread blocked" error - you were using the corecursive result without defining it.

```
λ fmap (take 10) . fixIO $ \fibs -> putStrLn "computing fibs" >> return (1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs))
computing fibs
[1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55]
```

Comment: `fix` is nothing to do with not keeping around the entire fibonacci sequence.  `let fibs = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs) in fibs !! 9` will do just as well.

Comment: Tom Ellis: I'm on my phone but I believe the definition of fix is `fix f = let a = f a in a`, so you're right, it's not necessary. but it is equivalent.

Comment: It can also be more succinct: `fix (1:)` is shorter than `let x=1:x in x`.

Comment: Note, that it only executes the monadic action once, as per the tightening law: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25814489/is-there-an-instance-of-monad-but-not-of-monadfix

Answer (score 5):

`fixIO` is the witness to the [`MonadFix IO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-Fix.html) instance.  See [the HaskellWiki page on MonadFix](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/MonadFix) and the paper [A Recursive do for Haskell](https://b846ad98-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/leventerkok/recdo.pdf).